# how to connect cassandra with logstash input?

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, logstash, logstash-configuration

Logstash.conf

> > input { tcp { port => 7199 } } output { elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost"] } }

Cassandra running on 7199 port and jhipster application running on localhost:8080.
we are unable to add into logstash by my_application

No log4j2 file found.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the JDBC plugin:

https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-jdbc

```
input {
   jdbc {
      jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:cassandra://hostname:XXXX" # Your port
      jdbc_user => "user" # The user value
      jdbc_password => "password" # The password
      jdbc_driver_library => "$PATH/cassandra_driver.jar" # Jar path
      jdbc_driver_class => "org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver" # Driver
      statement => "SELECT * FROM keyspace.my_table" # Your query
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The issue was solved by downloading a Cassandra JDBC from [DatabaseSchema](https://dbschema.com/jdbc-driver/Cassandra.html).

also when You want to add the jar files, add it in the 
logstashFolder/logstash-core/lib/jar

there seems to be a bug with logstash which only looks this path for external jar files.

also if there were some jar files that were duplicated use the latest ones.

Comment: Can you please share what are all jars are required to connect to cassandra from logstash. I downloaded cassandra-jdbc-driver-1.3.jar form DBSchema and configured driver class (com.dbschema.CassandraJdbcDriver), but it still did not work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply copy all the Jar files retrieved from DBSchema to the path said above: logstashFolder/logstash-core/lib/jar. in this folder there are already some jars that is required for logstash. don't delete them; simply add all the Jar files that is in DBSchema. Also if you see there are two jar files that are same delete the older version.