# How to copy data from Cassandra to elastic search 6.7

Tags: java, apache-spark, elasticsearch, cassandra, spark-streaming

I need to copy data from Cassandra to Elastic search. In Cassandra table is having almost 5TB data.
I am using the datastax "spark-cassandra-connector_2.11" connector to connect to  Cassandra.
And trying to use Elastic search spark streaming API. 
But due to huge data the data the indexing is not getting started.
Please correct me if wrong.

```
JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
CassandraJavaRDD<CassandraRow> cassandraJavaRDD = CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(sparkContext).cassandraTable(keyspace,table);
JavaRDD<String> dataRDD = cassandraJavaRDD.select("value").map(new Function<CassandraRow, String>() {
    @Override
    public String call(CassandraRow cassandraRow) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("cassandraRow");
        return cassandraRow.getString("value");
    }
});
List<String> dataList = dataRDD.collect();

JavaStreamingContext javaStreamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkContext, Seconds.apply(1));
Queue<JavaRDD<String>> microbatches = new LinkedList<JavaRDD<String>>();
microbatches.add(dataRDD);
JavaDStream<String> javaDStream = javaStreamingContext.queueStream(microbatches);
JavaEsSparkStreaming.saveJsonToEs(javaDStream, "index_spark/productDoc");
javaStreamingContext.start();
```

Is any other way to make parallel the stream of reading and writing ?

Comment: Have you tried with Logstash? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46271097/4604579 + https://medium.com/@alain.rastoul/pushing-cassandra-logs-into-elasticsearch-9be3b52af754

Comment: I dont want logs. i am trying to copy data..

Comment: Nothing to do with logs, Logstash is an ETL with multiple input/output. You can pick a `jdbc` input for selecting data from Cassandra and an `elasticsearch` output for sinking them to ES.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Actually we need some data transformation like remove few nodes in Json and updating few fields. Can that also be achieved if we fallow this approach ?

Comment: Logstash is a great tool for sourcing data from pretty much anywhere (`input`), applying transformations on the data (`filter`) and then sinking it pretty much anywhere as well (`output`). So without knowing more about your use case(s), Logstash would be a good candidate